# From sets A and B, find enough distinct pairs with unique appearances of the elements

Tags: combinatorics

Here's a rather deceptively simple problem that I came across in a real world setting.

Suppose that you have two sets $A$ and $B$ with elements $a_1, .., a_m$ and $b_1,...,b_n$. You are given a set of pairs $R=\{(a_i,b_j)\}$, which you don't choose yourself.

From these, we want to select $k$ pairs such that each $a_i$ and $b_j$ is only in one pair. Not all $a$s or $b$s need to appear in a selected pair.

For instance, if the number of distinct $a_i$s that appear in the set of pairs are less than $k$, then it is impossible. If exactly $k$ different $b_i$s appear in a pair, but somehow $a_1$ is the only $a$ that shares a pair with $b_1$ and $b_2$, then both of those can't appear and we fail again.

Is there any way to quickly tell if it is possible to find $k$ such pairs without brute forcing? I made some doodles and it seems like some graph theoretical argument (counting edges per vertex or similar) could do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $k \le \min(m,n)$.

For a special simple case:
$$ A = \{a_{1}, a_{2}\},  B = \{b_{1}, b_{2}\} $$
Then $k \le 2$. Take the maximum possible $k$, $k=2$. It is easy to select two pairs:
$$ (a_{1}, b_{1}), (a_{2}, b_{2}) $$

For a general case:
$$ A = \{a_{1}, ..., a_{m}\}, B = \{b_{1}, ..., b_{n} \} $$
Without loss of generality, let $m \le n$. Then $k \le m$. Now if $k=m$, we can select $m$ easy pairs that include all $a$s:
$$ P = \{(a_{1}, x_{1}), ..... , (a_{m}, x_{m})\} $$
then the $x$s can be different elements in $B$.

Now what if $k < m$? then just take $k$ distinct pairs from $P$.

Comment: Just to clarify, the question is about a set of given pairs and not about constructing new pairs : - )